# ¿cómo puedo cargar videos desde django a mi template?

Tags: python, django

Lo he intentando colocando

```
<source src="/static/{{video.video.mp4}}" type="video/mp4">
```

pero el video no se visualiza en mi template

Comment: accediendo a esa tura directo en la url lo carga? ya creastes el `STATICFILES_DIRS`??

Comment: Donde tienes el video, en tu carpeta static o en tus archivos medios